# Interpretation of the hazard ratio in a Cox regression

Tags: interpretation, cox-model, hazard

My question is referring to this paper: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/epidemiology-and-infection/article/mortality-and-survival-of-covid19/21C4D2B412AFFBF92FA7C0A09D456B02

To summarize, the authors use a dataset of 2'070 cases of COVID-19, of which 131 died (6.3% case fatality ratio). They perform a Cox regression and report the Hazard ratios as follows:

[image]

How would you compute the probability of death (given one is a positive case) for a person in absence of any risk factor (i.e. a healthy young person)?

How would you compute the probability for an elderly person with a cardiovascular disease and obesity (but no other disease)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of survival longer than control for an elderly person with cardiovascular disease and obesity is 0.008 (0.22 x 0.1 x 0.37).

Probability of survival longer than control: 0.22 elderly, 0.1 CVD,
0.43 DM, 0.22 blood dis, 0.2 neurol dis, 0.37 obesity, 0.28 pneumonia, 0.59 kidney dis.

The probability of survival longer than control (probability index)  is 1- HR/(HR + 1).
On the interpretation of the hazard ratio in Cox regression 2021
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/bimj.201800255